# PHP Restart Lighttpd doesn't return

Tags: php, bash, init.d

I have a php script which needs to restart lighttpd.  The php page never returns to the client.  I believe that is because the call doesn't return.  Here is my code:

```
 <?php

 exec("/etc/init.d/lighttpd restart");
 echo "Restarted!";

 ?>
```

If I comment out the exec line it returns as expected.
How can I get this call to return?

Thanks,

EV

Comment: are you shure that the apache/php user is allowed to exec the /etc/init.d/lighttpd script? by default root is allowed to execute the init.d scrips and apache don't run with root user ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you restart you httpd process your scripts will be terminated, no matter what you do!

You will never make any scripts to return a value directly from PHP. To make that work you should add a javascript and check for a `200` Status Code.

Comment: Good call.  That was a stupid question.  It must be like 2am. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's because your script kills the existing Lighthttpd process before it is able to return the result of the execution...

It is like having a process that kills himself and wondering why the process is not returning anything...